# Custom email sending in magento custom module

Tags: magento, email

I am working on a module that will send an email after 7 days of order completion. I'm stuck on sending emails. I can see the email template in transactional emails drop down in admin. But the email is not being sent.

Here is my confix.xml part for including email template.

```
<template>
        <email>
            <recurring_order_email_template translate="label">
                <label>Recurring order email</label>
                <file>coeus_recurring_order_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </recurring_order_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>
```

and this is how I am sending email in controller action

```
 $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->loadDefault('coeus_recurring_order_email');

    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
    $emailTemplateVariables['var1'] = 'var1 value';
    $emailTemplateVariables['var2'] = 'var 2 value';
    $emailTemplateVariables['var3'] = 'var 3 value';

    $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

   $emailTemplate->setSenderName('sender name');
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('sender@test.com');
    try {
        $emailTemplate->send('myemail@gmail.com', 'bla bla',$emailTemplateVariables);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I don't know why its not working.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
 $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('recurring_order_email_template');

//Getting the Store E-Mail Sender Name.
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

//Getting the Store General E-Mail.
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

//Variables for Confirmation Mail.
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['name'] = $customerName;
$emailTemplateVariables['email'] = $customerEmail;

//Appending the Custom Variables to Template.
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

//Sending E-Mail to Customers.
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
 ->setToName($senderName)
 ->setToEmail($customerEmail)
 ->setBody($processedTemplate)
 ->setSubject('Subject :')
 ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
 ->setFromName($senderName)
 ->setType('html');
 try{
 //Confimation E-Mail Send
 $mail->send();
 }
 catch(Exception $error)
 {
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
 return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Man Kingdom. its working as you explained.

Comment: Welcome @murtza !. Its for my pleasure!

Comment: @ManKingdom In above `$mail` How to add reply to email?

Comment: I am getting "Authentication failed: Maximum credits exceeded" Error. Any one have idea on this ? My code is perfect is this a sever side issue ?

Comment: Important to notice that the loadDefault('recurring_order_email_template') is related with the xml tag of the config and not the name of the template file kind of obvious but it make me loose some time...

Comment: @ManiprakashChinnasamy What's the Class equivalent for `core/email_template` etc... in Magetno 2 thanks

Answer (score 4):

Change your etc/config.xml code to below:

```
<template>
        <email>
            <recurring_order_email_template>
                <label>Recurring order email</label>
                <file>coeus_recurring_order_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </recurring_order_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>
```

Change your controller code to below:

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->loadDefault('recurring_order_email_template');

    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
    $emailTemplateVariables['var1'] = 'var1 value';
    $emailTemplateVariables['var2'] = 'var 2 value';
    $emailTemplateVariables['var3'] = 'var 3 value';

   $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

   $emailTemplate->setSenderName('sender name');
   $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('sender@test.com');
    try {
   $emailTemplate->send($recipientEmail, $senderName, $emailTemplateVariables);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Change your $recipientEmail, $senderName & $emailTemplateVariables as per your need.

To load a email template, you must specifiy the tag name after

```
<template>
            <email>
       </email>
</template>
```

that you provided in the config.xml

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake here.

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('coeus_recurring_order_email');
```

try this

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->loadDefault('recurring_order_email_template');
```

to load a email template you have to give the tag name that you provide in the config.xml

**eg:** in you code

use

```
<recurring_order_email_template>
```

to load email template