# Why would using the `send()` function of Magento's `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` model affect styling?

Tags: php, css, magento

For some odd reason, when I use the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` model, I cannot actually send an email without it affecting the page's styling.

Granted, I haven't set up the styling.  There is only one design picked under `System->Design` in the admin section, and it is set as `polar/retail`.

What happens, is that the design, just for the confirmation page of the order, is switched to the "default" style, e.g. `polar/default`.

I exported the database and did a text search for a possible offending column in some table that was set to `polar/default` `polar-default`, or `polar_default`, but there was nothing.

The rest of the site is good.

This is quite literally what my code is:

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$emailTemplate->loadDefault('order_nobpid_email');
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('No BP ID Set for Customer ' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '. Order: ' . $order->getIncrementId());
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($sender['email']);
$emailTemplate->setSenderName($sender['name']);
$result = $emailTemplate->send($recipient['email'], $recipient['name']);
```

When I comment out the `send()` function, the confirmation page has the correct styling and design.  When I allow the function, the design gets messed up.

What does the email have to do with the page's design?  I tried to follow the function calls, but I couldn't find anything useful.

To give some visuals of the issue:

---

When enabling the `send()` function, I get this.

[image: When enabling the <code>send()</code> function, I get this.]

---

When commenting out the `send()` function, I get this, which is correct.

[image: When commenting out the <code>send()</code> function, I get this, which is correct.]

---

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22087572/925058.

Comment: You can also wrap you code inside a try{}catch(){} statement to see if errors pop-up there that are launched before design rendering.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've located that Stack Overflow question before.  I have attempted to wrap the whole thing and separate parts into try/catch blocks, but there aren't any exceptions occurring.  I did figure out a workaround, though - I'll post it.